# Refresh a jquery dialog box on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery dialog box which is popped up on a button click. After some operations the dialog box is populated. There are few buttons which onclick does some functions. After the click of those buttons if I click on the buttons again it doesnt reload all the functions. hence I want to introduce a refresh button so that the dialog box refreshes. How can I achieve this?

```
<input type="button" id="sample" onclick="fnSettings()"/>

function fnSettings(){
 var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        title: 'Details',                  
        width: 700,
        height: 750,
        resizable: false
}
```

In this dialog box I have introduced a refresh button using html code. what functionality should I provide that button so that the dialog is refreshed?

Comment: what do you mean by `refresh dialog` ?  `does some functions` doesn't tell anyone what has happened to it since you initialized it

Comment: @charlietfl : Sir  I mean refresh the dialog box like how it appeared first time. there are few buttons and drop downs which are inside dialog box. Few functionalities change them and populate drop downs. I want to introduce a refresh button so after populating if user clicks refresh the dialog box should be fresh like how it appeared first time without any values

Comment: either store a copy of original html to replace it or keep track of what needs to be undone and set up methods to put it back.

Comment: Is there no function to reload the dialog box? so that i can call that onclick of a button?

Comment: that's why I'm suggesting you store the original html and replace it. Can do both using `html()` method